# Does systemd honour KILL order from chkconfig

Tags: fedora, systemd, fedora-18, init-script

Title of the question is just what I needed to ask. I don't see it actually following that. Is there a way, in which I can make systemd follow the KILL order.

From what I see, it just reverses the start order while killing/stopping processes.

Answer (score 0):

The systemd generator for sysvinit compatibility will attempt to honor the special [LSB headers](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/initscrcomconv.html) like **Required-Start**, but I don't think it follows the explicit ordering. I really recommend just writing a proper systemd service unit file with the right dependencies. See the Fedora Magazine article [systemd: Converting sysvinit scripts](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-converting-sysvinit-scripts/), which covers the basics of what you need to know to do so.